# Where can I find the logs of IRC Charm School?

Tags: community, juju, irc

I am looking for the logs of the freenode juju charms class that occurred on the 2nd of December, 2011.

Do they exist? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IRC Logs are always posted here:

- https://juju.ubuntu.com/CharmSchool

I have the log for this specific session here:

https://gist.github.com/1424323

You'll want to filter out the /joins and /parts, but have fun, and enjoy reading!

There is also the entire [channel log available here on irclogs.ubuntu.com](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2011/12/02/%23juju.html#t15:05)